# When running a java command with the -jar option, can you supply additional libraries using -cp?

Tags: java

When calling java command line using the `-jar` option:

```
java -jar connector-plugin-client.jar
```

Can you include additional libraries with `-cp`?

```
java -jar connector-plugin-client.jar -cp ojdbc8.jar
```

I know I can do

```
java -cp "connector-plugin-client.jar:ojdbc8.jar" the.main.MainClass
```

But wondering if that was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. When using `-jar`, the class path is entirely defined by the jar itself and the `Class-Path` entry in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the jar. It is not possible to add additional jars or directories to the class path using `-cp`.

In other words, `-cp` and `-jar` are mutually exclusive: you must choose one or the other.